# Проблема с отображением русских символов в TreeView JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, treeview

Создаю элемент Hyperlink для отображения в "дереве", когда задаю ему имя напрямую на выходе вместо текста имею знаки вопроса. Кодировку строки менял на UTF-8, меняется только внешний вид этих вопросов.

```
Hyperlink root = new Hyperlink();
    root.setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font.font("Arial")); 
    //Смена шрифта не помогает
    root.setText("Любой текст русскими буквами");
    //Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru")); //Пробовал, не работает
    TreeItem<Hyperlink> rootItem = new TreeItem<Hyperlink>(root);
```

Причем, другие узлы дерева создаю программно в цикле и названию присваиваю элемент массива String. Текст при этом отображается корректно.

```
for (String[] str: arrayList)

        {
            rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Hyperlink>(new Hyperlink(str[2])));
        }
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите с чем это может быть связано и какие могут быть пути решения? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Довольно странно, я сейчас у себя запустил код ( создал просто HyperLink и вывел ее на Stage) у меня все нормально отобразилась.

Comment: Как я понимаю, косяк связан конкретно с Hyperlink и Treeview

Comment: А попробуй сделать не HyperLink, а Label - у тебя там тоже будет непонятно что?

Comment: Оказалось, что дать имя Label'у тем же способом приводит к той же проблеме. Причем неважно в Treeview или в каком либо контейнере

Comment: а какую IDE ты используешь?

Comment: Intellij IDEA последней версии

Comment: зайди в настройки -> File encoding -> и выставь там везде UTF-8. Пересобери класс и запусти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо @Andrew Bystrov его способ, конкретно для IDEA, помог!

> зайди в настройки -> File encoding -> и выставь там везде UTF-8. Пересобери класс и запусти.

Правда все комментарии на русском придется переписать. В любом случае, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обернуть текст в html, Swing/JavaFX [поддерживают](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) ряд тэгов.

Comment: Обернул строку в <html></html> в конструкторе гиперссылки и через свойство .setText - не помогло(